# Version code 2 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-play

```
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.file_provider_paths"
                   android:resource="@xml/files_path"></meta-data>
</provider>-->
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--<uses-permission android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

I changed version code and version name also still getting above error meassage in play console  dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open **Properties** under your android project, open `AndroidManifest.xml`, find `android:versionCode` in the  tag, your versionCode should be 2, please increase your versionCode, and then republish your application.